# Turning stereo sound into mono output to normalize unbalanced channels?

Tags: sound, vlc

For example in this video the right channel is much louder and that's really annoying when using headphones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOAgplgTxfc

I'd like to either

- output only one channel to both speakers, or
- combine two channels into one and then output it to both speakers.

Preferably without the need to edit file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to "tools" and select "effects and filters" then under "Audio effects" go to "spatializer" and enable that. now try to listen that track again.

Most probably that problem will be gone after that. You can also take it to mono if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, that's working, thanks. What exactly do you mean in "take it to mono"?

Comment: And don't forget to switch it off afterwards. >_<

Comment: For the spatializer: it works best if you turn down all the sliders except for "dry".

Answer (score 2):

A faster solution would be:

1. Right-click on the video frame.
2. Select **Audio**.
3. Select **Stereo Mode**.
4. Select **Monaural**.

**EDIT:** Using *VLC 3.0.7.1 Vetinari* in *KDE Neon*

Comment: Thanks you! I can't verify it right now but I'll accept it as the main answer in case anyone else confirms it's working

Comment: That worked for me.  Apparently, this **downmixes audio to mono**.  
 I was watching some classes and channels were unbalanced. It was annoying hearing with headphones on and I almost thought they had some problem.  
Then I perceived that whenever the professor moved his head, the sound got unbalanced and that the video was the real problem, not my set.  
I can't guarantee that all versions of VLC offer this simple fix.  
Also, it is not persistent (settings reset when I close the program), but I know that it exists two-clicks away.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, `pan` `mplayer` filter worked:

`mplayer -af pan=1:1 filename`

A working solution for VLC is still preferable if anyone will find any.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your video window> interface> effects & filters> Audio Effects> Spacializer> Enable

Turn all sliders down to zero except 'Dry' which should be set to max (10.0)

This makes VLC mono

Comment: Upon testing making the sound dry does not make VLC mono (sound from one side is lost)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the Spatializer filter, with terrible results.

A generic and simple solution is to remap the Pulseaudio sink.

Run the following and take note of the sink the application is using:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

Then run the following, replacing `<NAME>` with the sink name found above:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=<NAME> channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

Now, from `pavucontrol`, you can switch the sink used by the application to the remapped one.

Answer (score 0):

Check `System Preferences` -> `Sound Settings` pref to adjust left/right speakers, in slider label called **"`Balance`"**.

[image: "Balance" slider in Sys Settings]
*For the record, I have 1 of 2 speakers broken, your question came to me the same way for a somewhat different issue/problem. Just converting "stereo to mono" made sense, but so does changing "Balance", so I do each to be double sure.*

(I still wish VLC did that natively to be sure it's working, as of Q1 2022 today it's ***still not a VLC feature***, but [the System should override VLC, correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272558/play-audio-to-only-one-speaker-left-right-from-commandline-using-libvlc#comment124780211_9272558))